# Android How to append SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a database created from a file in my assests folder. When the app is upgraded I want the new file in that folder to add (append) to the current database. I am currently trying to use this script below, but it is not working. I is just not adding to the db.

```
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(STATIC_DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = STATIC_DB_PATH + STATIC_DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using the [SQLLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and implementing the onUpgrade method. In that method (only called when your database version number -- something you maintain-- is incremented), you can then open your asset file and use it to execute inserts/updates into the sqllite DB.

So in this case, store the SQL commands in the file and then read each line and run with db.execSQL:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(STATIC_DB_NAME));
String line  = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){
  db.execSQL(line); 
  line = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: This is running from within the onUpgrade but I am unable to get it to append.

Comment: Don't append directly to the file. Use the input to execute sql commands to insert/update. See my edited answer for exactly what I mean.

Comment: the file i am importing is an sqlite database not a list of queries. Would this still work. I am thinking not.

Comment: no, it won't. You can't, however, append 1 sqlite db to another and still end up with a valid database. You're better off storing your upgrade procedures as a set of sql instructions and executing them as a series of dml statements.